# Correct Syntax in Client Template to add Actionlink along with conditional statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried number of attempts to add html.actionlink  along with the condition in client template in kendo grid. Can please anyone help with the correct syntax.
Thanks.

```
col.Bound(o => o.IsEmpolymentFileExist).ClientTemplate("# if( IsEmpolymentFileExist == true) { # @Html.ActionLink("OpenFile", "Openfile", "PreEmploymentWorkflow", new { Id = "#=PreEmploymentId#", uploadfilename = "Employment Application" }, new { @class = "classname3" }).ToHtmlString() # } else {# <img ... /> # } #")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the template syntax enclosed in quotes then the action link then the final template syntax: "... template ...**" +** @Html.Actionlink(...).ToHtmlString() **+ "**... template ...", so try:

```
.ClientTemplate("# if( IsEmpolymentFileExist == true) { #" + @Html.ActionLink("OpenFile", "Openfile", "PreEmploymentWorkflow", new { Id = "#=PreEmploymentId#", uploadfilename = "Employment Application" }, new { @class = "classname3" }).ToHtmlString() + "# } else {# <img ... /> # } #")
```

Not sure `{# <img ... /> # }` needs to be inside hashes either.